Find Polynomials satisfying the relation.
Show that for every $n\geq1$  there exist $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ of degree $n$ and $n-1$ respectively such that
$\left(P\left(x\right)\right)^2-1=\left(x^2-1\right)\left(Q\left(x\right)\right)^2$
I am trying to use induction here for $n=1$ $P(x)=x$ and $Q(x)=1$.
by rararranging $\left(P\left(x\right)\right)^2-\left(x^2-1\right)\left(Q\left(x\right)\right)^2=1$.
This show $gcd(((P(x))^2,(Q(x))^2)=1$ hence not common root so $gcd(((P(x)),(Q(x)))=1$
or $gcd(P(x),Q(x))=1$ i am not able to proceed furthur. any hints to proceed.

Try small cases, What's the solution for $n=2, 3$? If you have that, it might be able to guide how to do the induction (or even indicate if induction is a reasonable approach)

actually i am trying to find a smart solution , using symmetry etc. direct calculation is tedius

$\frac{\left(P\left(x\right)\right)^2-1}{\left(x^2-1\right)}=\left(Q\left(x\right)\right)^2$

I don't think induction is a good approach here, so am trying to hint that to you. $\quad$ There is a smart solution to this problem. Finding $n = 2, 3$ might help with discovering it.

$\frac{\left(P\left(x\right)\right) -1}{\left(x-1\right)}=\left(Q\left(x\right)\right)$

will this work here

No, because there is not a true statement. You cannot just randomly apply square roots. that's much like saying "Since 25 = 9 + 16, hence 5 = 3+4."

okay i will be back when i finde for $n=2$ and $n=3$

after my work for $n=2$ i get $P(x)=2x^2-1$ and $Q(x)=2x$, after some time i will post for $n=3$.

@CalvinLin for n=3 $P(x)= 4x^3-3x$ and $Q(x)=4x^2-1$.

You may want to read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Pell_equation_definition

As hinted by Macavity, you found the Chebyshev polynomial family of solutions. With that understanding of when $\cos \theta = 0, \sin \theta = \pm 1$, you can see why the condition is satisfied. $\quad$ There's another family of solutions called the Legendre polynomials. This follows from showing that $P'(x) = k Q(x)$ and solving the differential equation $2kP(x) =2xP'(x) + (x^2-1)P''(x)$.

@CalvinLin i found this question in mathematics Excalibur and I think to solve this we really don't need to know differential equations

Like I said, the first family of solutions only uses trigonometric identities. Coming up with that / making that guess is prefectly reasonable up to the IMO level. $\quad$ I'm just providing fuller context if one is interested in finding ALL solutions, which isn't what the question asked for. Furthermore, if this was a Putnam problem (you didn't state the source initially, so you can't use our lack of mind-reading skills against us), differential equations would be reasonable too.

can you elaborate more on trig identites i know chebyshev polynomial can give tri formulas for $cos k\theta$

Did you read through the link that Macavity sent? If no, read it. If yes, be specific about what you want elaborated on. We're not here to spoon-feed you all possible information, without you demonstrating any effort.

@CalvinLin I have check and putting you substitution $P'(x)=kQ(x)$ which i can write $P'(x)/k=Q(x)$ and getting the chebyshev differential equation $k^2 P(x) = (xP'(x) + (x^2 - 1)P^{\prime\prime}(x)).$ please clarify i am not getting legendre diff  equation.

Ah, my Legendre polynomial comment was made in error. I knew that $(P(x)^2 - 1) / (x^2-1)$ was a polynomial and it had a similar DEQ with the $(x^2-1)$, but it doesn't work out. (EG Legendre polynomials do not satisfy the equation, the rational expression wasn't a perfect square, etc) So we might just have 1 solution for each $n$ (up to $\pm$).

Okay now everything is clear
